# Symfony2 get item type in forms

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I have a form, and need the field type in the bindrequest, the method getType dont works fine:

```
$peticion = $this->getRequest();
        if ($peticion->getMethod() == 'POST') 
        {
            $form->bindRequest($peticion);

            if ($form->isValid()) {

             foreach($form as $key => $per)
                       $per->getType(); // i want the type of item [text,checkbox,etc] the method getType() dont work
 }}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this:

```
foreach($form as $key => $per) {
    $per->getConfig()->getType()->getName();
}
```